# I can't set the background using CSS in my Flask app

Tags: python, css, flask

I'm creating a web app with Flask. I created a style.css file and was able to use it successfully to specify some table attributes. But when I try to use code from CSS Tricks to add a background image for my landing page, the image fails to show.

CSS:

```
html {

    /* Source: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ */
    background: url(static/landing_page.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I created a simple test.html file that uses the same CSS and it worked (the image showed up, and was scaled properly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using built in function **url_for** you can get this inside jinja html, just place this on your css style

```
url("{{url_for('static',filename="landing_page.jpg")}}");
```

In general when you refer to a static file , a common practice is to target it through **url_for** function.

Answer (score 3):

The URL needs to be `url(landing_page.jpeg)`, not `url(static/landing_page.jpeg)`.